# Creating a Regular Expression with boundery

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a Regex in c#,I write the following code:

```
        string temp = "happ";
        Regex reg = new Regex(temp + @"((\G(iness))|(\G(ily))*)\b");
        string str = "happily happiness happy";    
        int x = reg.Matches(str).Count;
```

My target that only "happily" and "happiness" will be found, so I write "\b", to limit the regex. but when the app runs always x eqquals zero, and when "\b" is dropped, x equals three.

Does anyone know why? 
Thanks
Rachel

Comment: What's the point of `\G` here?

Comment: I don't quite see how it is supposed to work. `(\G(ily))*` also bothers me... What about `\bhapp(iness|ily)\b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\G` never matches here I think. It makes only sense at the beginning of an expression, since it says that the expression should directly follow the previous match.

If you omit `\b`, your expression matches three times "happ", if you use `\b`, "happ" cannot be matched and therefore the count is zero.

Use something like

```
@"happ(iness|ily)\b"
```

as Kobi suggestes in his comment.

Comment: I tried it and this cod's line doing well. I thought that if I want that all group will be found I should write "\G". thankes

Comment: @Rachel, if this worked for you be sure to mark the answer as correct